# Calling a dataframe within a function with if else statements

Tags: python, dataframe, function, return-value

I have if statements within a function (with parameters) to choose a server, connect to the database, select the view and create a dataframe.

```
def server(server_name, database_name, view_name):
    if server_name=="local":
        import pandas as pd
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        import pymysql
        print('Connecting to the LOCAL database...')
        db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/' + database_name
        db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
        df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM ' + view_name, con=db_connection,parse_dates=['encounter_date'])
        return df  

    elif server_name=="cloud":
        import pandas as pd
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        import pymysql
        print('Connecting to the CLOUD database...')
        db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/' + database_name
        db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
        df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM ' + view_name, con=db_connection,parse_dates=['encounter_date'])
        return df  

else:
    print(".....")
```

I have the code above in a file called 'custom_functions.py'

Then from another file, i'm calling it as follows:

```
import custom_functions as cf
cf.server("local","local_db","vw_local")
```

This automatically shows the dataframe but whenever I call 'df' from another line in jupyter, it's saying that it's not defined.

I am using jupyter note book so I have one row for this:

```
import custom_functions as cf
cf.server("local","local_db","vw_local")
```

Then I want to have another line and call:

```
df.head()
```

or anything to call the dataframe

Comment: This has nothing to do with modules, nothing to do with databases, nothing to do with Pandas and nothing to do with Jupyter. It has everything to do with *how to call a function and use the result*. If you do not understand such fundamentals, you need to review a tutorial before trying to write a project this complicated. You are trying to run before you can crawl.

Comment: For future reference, please also read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough.